# C# code works in one script, but not the other

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am currently learning C# as I'm studying a Games Design Course at University. I am currently implementing a system where: when the time reaches 0, the game pauses and ends. This works :).

However, at first I tried implementing the code into another script - but doesn't work on that script. This has puzzled me. Here is the code (that works):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text TimeText;
    public float HealthTimer;
    public bool TimeIsRunning;
    public GameObject CanvasEnd;
  
    void Start()
    {
        
        TimeText = GameObject.Find("Timer").GetComponent<Text>();
        TimeIsRunning = true;

        CanvasEnd.SetActive(false);

    }


    void Update()
    {
        TimeText.text = HealthTimer.ToString("0");

        if (TimeIsRunning == true)
        {
            if (HealthTimer > 0)
            {
                HealthTimer -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                CanvasEnd.SetActive(true);
            }

            if(HealthTimer == 0)
            {
                TimeIsRunning = false;
                HealthTimer = 0;
            }

        }
```

This script is directly attached to the timer. But I don't understand why it doesn't work when I implement it into another script (that already controls other game aspects). There were no errors, and everything was declared properly.

The exact same code was put into this script (in void update) and didn't work:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject PlayerTracker;
    public GameObject BlueBottle;
    public GameObject GreenBottle;
    public GameObject RedBottle;
    public GameObject ChestCanvas;
    public float Score;
  
    public float ChestScoreK = 0;
    private Text HT;
    private Text HC;
    private Text Port;
    private Text TimeText;
    
   
    float speed = 4;
    float rotSpeed = 80;
    float rot = 0f;
    float gravity = 8;
    // Variables counting Blue, Red and Green bottles
    public int BBCounter = 0;
    public int RBCounter = 0;
    public int GBCounter = 0;
    public int CCounter = 0;
    Vector3 moveDir = Vector3.zero;

    CharacterController controller;
    Animator anim;


   

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        ChestCanvas.SetActive(false);
        TimeText = GameObject.Find("Timer").GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {

//Script was implemented here

       




        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                anim.SetInteger("condition", 1);
                moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                moveDir *= speed;
                moveDir = transform.TransformDirection (moveDir);
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
            {
                anim.SetInteger("condition", 0);
                moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        rot += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, rot, 0);

        moveDir.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PlayerTracker.transform.position = Player.transform.position;
       

    }



    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    
        
    
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "BlueBottle")
        {
            Debug.Log("BLUE");
            BBCounter = BBCounter + 1;
           

            GameObject MasterScriptBlue = GameObject.Find("GameMaster");
            MasterScriptBlue.GetComponent<GameMasterScript>();
            MasterScriptBlue.GetComponent<GameMasterScript>().BlueBottleCounter = BBCounter;
                                   
            
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedBottle")
        {
            Debug.Log("RED");
            RBCounter = RBCounter + 1;
            GameObject MasterScriptRed = GameObject.Find("GameMaster");
            MasterScriptRed.GetComponent<GameMasterScript>();
            MasterScriptRed.GetComponent<GameMasterScript>().RedBottleCounter = RBCounter;

            

        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "GreenBottle")
        {
            Debug.Log("GREEN");
            GBCounter = GBCounter + 1;
            GameObject MasterScriptGreen = GameObject.Find("GameMaster");
            MasterScriptGreen.GetComponent<GameMasterScript>();
            MasterScriptGreen.GetComponent<GameMasterScript>().GreenBottleCounter = GBCounter;

            
        }

        if(other.gameObject.tag == "CityCollider")
        {

            GameObject HuntingCity = GameObject.Find("HC");
            Destroy(HuntingCity);

            ScoringSystem.theScore += 100;

            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Destroyed");

        }

        if(other.gameObject.tag == "TownCollider")
        {
            GameObject HuntingTown = GameObject.Find("HT");
            Destroy(HuntingTown);
            

            ScoringSystem.theScore += 100;

            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Destroyed");

            Debug.Log("Destroyed");
        }


        if(other.gameObject.tag == "PortCollider")
        {
            GameObject Port = GameObject.Find("Port");
            Destroy(Port);

            ScoringSystem.theScore += 100;

            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Destroyed");


        }

       if(other.gameObject.tag == "Chest")
        {

            Time.timeScale = 0;
            ChestCanvas.SetActive(true);

            ChestScoreK += 1;
            GameObject MasterScriptChest = GameObject.Find("GameMaster");
            MasterScriptChest.GetComponent<GameMasterScript>().ChestScore += ChestScoreK;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            GameObject HealthScript = GameObject.Find("Timer");
            HealthScript.GetComponent<Health>().TimeIsRunning = false;
        }

    }
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: I thought I added the one that didnt work also one sec

Comment: Done, it includes both scripts now, and where the code was implemented. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand the problem from your question, but if you are looking for potential problems in your script then it looks like you are comparing a `float` to zero here:

```
        if(HealthTimer == 0)
        {
            TimeIsRunning = false;
            HealthTimer = 0;
        }
```

So it is possible that `HealthTimer` is never exactly zero.

You probbaly want `if (HealthTimer <= 0f)` instead, or to move that block into the `else` block of your preceding `if` statement.

Other differences with the second script are:

- the second script is not setting `TimeIsRunning = true;` in the `Start()` method,
- other methods set `Time.timeScale = 0;` in the second script (not sure what impact this has, but may be relevant).

Comment: Actually, yeah that seems like a better way of doing it, thanks. I'm just confused how the code works fine, when implemented into a new script though.

Comment: Now you've posted the second script, I've updated the answer with a couple more suggestions of things to check.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same 'using' tags at the top of your scripts? The 'text' class only exists in UnityEngine.UI, and not UnityEngine.

Comment: Yeah I do, my bad for not showing it on here.